# can a sum of two non-compact operators be compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

I'm supposed to say, whether an operator
$$Tf(t)=f(1-t)$$
can be expressed as
$$T=\lambda I-K$$
where $K$ is a compact operator. As $T$ is not compact, I suppose that $K=\lambda I-T$ can't be compact either, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Just to give a stupid answer to the question in the title: consider $T$ and $-T$.

Comment: makes sense. thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Even more, if $K$ is a compact operator on an infinite-dimensional normed space and $\lambda\neq 0$, then $T:=\lambda I-K$ will never be compact (because $\lambda I=K+T$ is not compact). If you are interested in your concrete example, you should add the space $T$ is acting on. It might be helpful to use that operators of the form $\lambda I-K$ are Fredholm operators with index $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I solved it:

I defined $(f_n)$ as:
$$f_n(x)=\chi(2n,2n+1)$$
where $\chi$ is the characteristic function. Follows
$$Kf_n(t)=\lambda f_n(t)-f_n(t-1)=\lambda\chi(2n,2n+1)-\chi(2n-1,2n)$$
now lets calculate $||f_n-f_m||_2$:
$$||f_n-f_m||_2=\sqrt{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^2}=\sqrt{2\lambda^2+2}$$
which means, that $\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{C}/\{0\}$ we can't choose a convergent subsequence from $(\lambda I-T)(f_n)\ \Rightarrow\ (\lambda I-T)$ can't be compact and $T$ can't be expressed as $\lambda I+K$